# How to quote files in other positions in Quarto in R?

Tags: r

I have a Quarto file named 'Quarto.qmd', now I want to quote the `level2.r` file in level2 folder through `Source ()`

My file structure is as follows:

```
root
  --level1.r
  level2folder
    --level2.r
  level2folder2
    --quarto.qmd
    --level2.r
```

And the code in 'quarTo.qmd' is as follows:

`source ("level2folder/level2.r")`

I have also tried

`Source("~/Level2Folder/Level2.r")`

`Source("./ level2Folder/Level2.r")`

but it was not successful, who can help me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding two points at the beginnin of the string to indicate to the code to go up in the folders level:

```
  source("../level2folder/level2.r")
```

Comment: I have tried it too, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I see, where is the working directory setted? You can check thar using getwd(). It's critical the working directory to be setted in the folder where the code relies